# HTML - Background image not appearing

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, html-helper

In the following snippet, the background image does not load. The image is saved in my computer.

I am using `style="background-image:src('Users\brian\Documents\Website KCITI\shoebill-uganda.jpg');"` to specify the background image.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
{
    margin:auto;
    padding:auto;
}
.top{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#008000 !important;
    border-bottom:2px solid #008000;
}
.top div{
    width:1200px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#800000 !important;
    font-family:calibri;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:right;
}

.logo{
    width:100%;
    background-color:;
    border-bottom:2px solid #f0f0f0;
}
.logo div{
    width:1200px;
    background-color:;
    font-family:calibri;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:left;
}
.logo div table a{
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:gray;
}
.logo div table a:hover{
    color:#428bca;
    border-bottom:2px solid gray;
}

.middle{
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:2px solid #f0f0f0;
}
.middle div{
    width:1200px;
    height:400px;
    font-family:calibri;
}
.middle div p{
    width:1000px;
    font-weight:bold;
    height:300px;
    color:#fff;
    opacity:0.2;
    font-size:50px;
    background-color:#000;
}

.bottom{
    width:100%;
    background-color:;
    border-bottom:2px solid #f0f0f0;
}
.bottom div{
    width:1200px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:;
    font-family:calibri;
    text-align:right;
}
.bottom div table{
    padding-top:30px;
    width:1100px;
    text-align:justify;
    color:gray;
    font-size:20px;
}

.bottom_up{
    width:100%;
    background-color:;
    border-bottom:2px solid #f0f0f0;
}
.bottom_up div{
    padding-top:20px;
    width:1200px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:;
    font-family:forte;
    font-size:30px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
.bottom_up div table{
    padding-top:30px;
    font-size:30px;
    width:1100px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:;
    font-family:calibri;
    
}

input[type="text"]{
    padding:12px;
    width:250px;
}
select{
    padding:12px;
    width:250px;
}
textarea{
    padding:50px;
    width:550px;
}
button{
    width:550px;
    padding:10px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:20px;
    background-color:#2FA5EB !important;
}


.nav_down{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#008000 !important;
    border-bottom:2px solid #f0f0f0;
}
.nav_down div{
    width:1200px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#800000;
    font-family:calibri;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:left;
}
</style>

    <title> Longclaw Expeditions </title>
    
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="top">
        <div>
         Contact Us +254712345678 | info@longclawexpeditions.com 
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="logo">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td width="600px" style="font-size:50px;font-family:Arial Black;"> <font color="#008000"> LONGCLAW  </font><font color="#800000
"> EXPEDITIONS</font> </td>
                    <td> <br> <br>
                        <font size="4px"> 
                            <a href="index.html">HOME</a> 
                            <a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a>  
                            <a href="destination.html">DESTINATION</a>
                            <a href="blogs.html">BLOGS</a> 
                            <a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="middle">
        <div style="background-image:src('Users\brian\Documents\Website KCITI\shoebill-uganda.jpg');">
        <p>
            <br> <br>
                    Tours and Travel  <br>
            <font size="5px"> The Wildlife and Birding Gurus </font>
        </p> 
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="bottom">
        <div>
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="700px">
                        <H1><font color="#008000"> Longclaw Expeditions </font></H2> 

                    <H2><font color="#800000" size="5px"> Don’t Listen to Them, Go and See by Yourself.</font></H2> <br> <br>

Since 2015, Longclaw Expedition has been focused on bringing our customers the best in esteem and quality travel game plans. We are enthusiastic about movement and sharing the world’s marvels on the relaxation travel side, and giving corporate explorers the best services to encourage their business travel needs. <br><br>

A solid and “believed” travel brand of Africa, our qualities incorporate a vast and faithful client base, a multi-channel stage for relaxation and business explorers, a powerful portable eco-framework for a range of voyagers and providers. Below are some of the services we offer.<br><br>
<ul>
<li> Airport Transfers
<li>Beach Safari
<li>Bush Safari
<li>Birding Safari
<li>Hotel Booking and Reservation
</ul>
<br>
 </td>
                    
                    
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
            
                
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="bottom_up">
        <div>
                <H2>Book a Safari</H2>
                
                <table>
                                        
                    <tr>
                        <td width="500px"> </td>
                        <td>    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
                        <td>    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="30px">
                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="500px"> </td>
                        <td>    <input type="text" placeholder="Email Id">
                        <td>    <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile No">
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr height="30px">
                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="500px"> </td>
                        <td>    <select> <option> -- Adults -- </option> <option> 1 </option> <option> 2 <option> 3 <option> 4 <option> 5 <option> 6 <option>  </option> </select>
                                                <td>    <select> <option> -- Kids -- </option> <option> 1 </option> <option> 2 <option> 3 <option> 4 <option> 5 <option> 6 <option>  </option> </select>
                                                <td>    <select> <option> -- Game Park -- </option> <option> Maasai Mara </option> <option> Tsavo National Park <option> Amboseli Natoina Park <option>Samburu National Park <option> Nairobi National Park <option> Nakuru National Park <option>  </option> </select>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                        <td>    <input type="text" placeholder="Booking date">    
                                        </tr>                                                                                      
                            
                    
                        <tr height="30px">
                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="500px"> </td>
                        <td colspan="2">    <textarea placeholder="Message"> </textarea>
                    </tr>
            

    

        
                        <tr height="30px">
                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="500px"> </td>
                        <td colspan="2">    <button> SUBMIT </button>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    <div class="nav_down">
        <div>
         &copy; Longclaw Expeditions 
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Its url  background-image: url("img_tree.gif"),

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues in the snippet you provided.

A) It should be `style="background-image:url('path-to-background-image');"` instead of `style="background-image:src('path-to-background-image');"`

B) The `path-to-background-image` is relative, so :

- If you are serving the page (say at `http://localhost:8080`), then the image is being looked for at the path `http://localhost:8001/Users/brian/Documents/Website%20KCITI/shoebill-uganda.png`
- If you are opening the HTML file directly in the browser, then the image is being looked for at `path-to-html-file/Users/brian/Documents/Website%20KCITI/shoebill-uganda.png`

You need to use the right syntax with the right path.

Generally, the images used in a web page are placed in the same directory as the source code (say in a separate `images` folder) to avoid such issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer will try it and share my results